# Getting image inside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, uicollectionview

I have a collection view. Every cell of this collection view has a UIIMageView marked with tag 100.

At one point, the cells are displayed. The user selects a cell. I want to make a copy of that image inside the imageView of that cell.

This is the code:

```
UICollectionViewCell *touchedCell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[touchedCell viewWithTag:100];

UIImage *image = imageView.image;
```

The problem is that at this point, image is nil. `touchedCell` and `imageView` are not nil.

Why is that and how do I obtain that image?

Comment: what do u mean by after user touches a cell, your implementation of the above code seems to be of `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: I don't think his will work with dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier. Where do you call this code?

Comment: Is the images showing in your collectionview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these--
First create an instance variable

```
@implementation MyClass {
 UIImage *newImage
}
```

Then
Implement this delegate method of collectionview

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
   didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

CustomCollectionViewCell *datasetCell = 
  (CustomCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cell.customImageVIew.oldImage.CGImage];
}
```

So your instance variable newImage will contain a copy of the image from the cell you selected.
Hope this helps